# Удаление элемента из стека

Tags: c++, алгоритм, стек

Имеется код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
struct stack {
    int inf;
    stack *next;
};
stack* addElements(stack *begin);
void showStack(stack *begin);
void deleteStack(stack **begin);
int menu();
void input(int &a);
stack* deleteMaxValue(stack *begin);
int main() {
    stack *begin = NULL;
    while (true) {
        switch (menu())
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Enter the element:" << endl;
            begin = addElements(begin);
            cout << "Element added" << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            showStack(begin);
            break;
        case 3:
            deleteStack(&begin);
            break;
        case 4:
            begin = deleteMaxValue(begin);
            break;
        case 0:
            cout << "Press Enter if you want to exit" << endl;
            if (_getch() == 13) {
                delete begin;
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Choose 1-4 or 0" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
stack* addElements(stack *begin) {
    int inf;
    input(inf);
    stack *t = new stack;
    t->inf = inf;
    t->next = begin;
    return t;
}
void showStack(stack *begin) {
    cout << "--------------Stack--------------" << endl;
    stack *t = begin;
    while (t != NULL) {
        cout << "\t\t"<<t->inf << endl;
        t = t->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
void deleteStack(stack **begin) {
    while ((*begin) != NULL) {
        stack *t = *begin;
        (*begin) = (*begin)->next;
        delete t;
    }
    cout << "Stack cleared" << endl;
}
int menu() {
    cout << "1 - add element" << endl;
    cout << "2 - show stack" << endl;
    cout << "3 - clear stack" << endl;
    cout << "4 - delete max element" << endl;
    cout << "0 - exit" << endl;
    int choise;
    input(choise);
    return choise;
}
void input(int &a) {
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> a;
        if (cin.good()) {
            break;
        }
        cout << "Wrong input" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
stack* deleteMaxValue(stack *begin) {
    stack *p = begin;
    stack *t = p->next;
    int max = t->inf;
    while (t != NULL) {
        if (t->inf > max) {
            max = t->inf;
        }
        t = t->next;
    }
    t = begin;
    while (t != NULL) {
        if (t->inf == max) {
            p->next = t->next;
            delete t;
            t = p->next;
        }
        else {
            p = t;
            t = t->next;
        }
    }
    t = begin;
    begin = begin->next;
    delete t;
    return begin;
}
```

Задача - удаление максимального элемента стека. Удаление происходит в функции `stack* deleteMaxValue(stack *begin)`, однако при стеке, содержащем, например,

> 3 2 1

, после удаления остаётся только 1. В чем ошибка и как от нее избавиться?

Answer (score 2):

Лучше проще да лучше

```
 stack* deleteMaxValue(stack *begin) {
    stack *t = begin, *p = begin->next;
    for (; p; p = p->next)   
        if(p->inf > t->inf)  t = p;    
    p = begin;  
    if (p != t) {
        while (p->next != t)   p = p->next;         
        p->next = t->next;
    }
    else 
        begin = t->next;
    delete t;    
    return begin;
}
```

По моему так, но может быть можно еще лучше

Answer (score 0):

У [@AR Hovsepyan](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/797923/217579) хорошая функция, но она удаляет только один максимальный элемент в стеке. Знаю, что это не совсем то, что было Вам нужно (так как это не функция, возвращающая stack*), но этот код может быть полезен другим людям. Он выполняет удаление всех максимальных элементов из стека

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // файловый ввод вывод легко изменить на консольный
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    // достаточно убрать данную строку и строку выше и заменить все "in" на "cin", 
    // а "out" на "cout"
    ofstream out("output.txt");
    stack <int> st1, st2;
    int i;
    while (in >> i){ //ввод
        st1.push(i);
    }
    //Пусть в iput: 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 6
    //Тогда в st1: 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 6
    //      в st2: NULL (нет элементов)
    int max = INT_MIN;
    while (!st1.empty()){ // Нахождение максимального
        i = st1.top(); 
        if ( i > max){
            max = i;
        }
        st1.pop();
        st2.push(i);
    }
    // Теперь в st1: NULL 
    //        в st2: 6 6 5 4 3 2 1 6
//    cout << max << endl;
    

    while(!st2.empty())//удаление элементов, равных макс.
    {                   
        i = st2.top();
        st2.pop();
        if(i != max){
            st1.push(i);
        }
    }
    //Теперь в st1: 1 2 3 4 5
    //       в st2: NULL
    while(!st1.empty())
    {
        i = st1.top();
        st1.pop();
        st2.push(i);
    }
    //Теперь в st1: NULL
    //       в st2: 5 4 3 2 1
    while (!st2.empty()){ //вывод
        i = st2.top();
        st2.pop();
        out << i << ' ';
    }
    //Вывод: 1 2 3 4 5   
    // То, что надо (все макс. элементы удалены, и стек выведен в правильном порядке)
    return 0;
}
```